# Gstreamer doesn't show video using QML code

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer, yocto

I have to develop a Qt/QML application for a [Yocto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yocto_Project)-based [OpenSTLinux](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/OpenSTLinux_distribution) system. This application has to play videos and audios. Below the "gstreamer" plugins, I have installed in my OpenSTLinux image:

gstreamer1.0 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad 
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly 
gstreamer1.0-rtsp-server 
gstreamer1.0-omx 
gstreamer1.0-libav 
gstreamer1.0-dev 
gst-validate 
gst-examples

Using the following line command,

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/root/media/video_test.mp4 video-sink="waylandsink sync=false"
```

the video and audio work correctly. Instead, using QML components, for example this

```js
Item {

    id: idVideo

    visible: true

    width: 1024
    height: 600

    Video {
        id: videoExample
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "file:///home/root/media/video_test.mp4"
        autoPlay: true

        focus: true
    }
}
```

or this,

```js
Item {

    id: idVideo

    visible: true

    width: 1024
    height: 600

    MediaPlayer {
        id: mdpExample
        source: "file:///home/root/media/video_test.mp4"
        autoPlay: true
    }


    VideoOutput {
        id: videoExample
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: mdpExample
    }
}
```

the audio plays correctly, but the video does not (the display is black). How can I solve the problem?

If I launch the following line command,

```
gst-inspect-1.0
```

I have the following answer:

```
dtmf:  dtmfsrc: DTMF tone generator
dtmf:  rtpdtmfsrc: RTP DTMF packet generator
dtmf:  rtpdtmfdepay: RTP DTMF packet depayloader
monoscope:  monoscope: Monoscope
imagefreeze:  imagefreeze: Still frame stream generator
goom:  goom: GOOM: what a GOOM!
flac:  flacenc: FLAC audio encoder
flac:  flacdec: FLAC audio decoder
flac:  flactag: FLAC tagger
wavparse:  wavparse: WAV audio demuxer
avi:  avidemux: Avi demuxer
avi:  avimux: Avi muxer
avi:  avisubtitle: Avi subtitle parser
spectrum:  spectrum: Spectrum analyzer
videobox:  videobox: Video box filter
soup:  souphttpsrc: HTTP client source
soup:  souphttpclientsink: HTTP client sink
goom2k1:  goom2k1: GOOM: what a GOOM! 2k1 edition
videomixer:  videomixer: Video mixer 2
rtsp:  rtspsrc: RTSP packet receiver
rtsp:  rtpdec: RTP Decoder
rtp:  rtpac3depay: RTP AC3 depayloader
rtp:  rtpac3pay: RTP AC3 audio payloader
rtp:  rtpbvdepay: RTP BroadcomVoice depayloader
rtp:  rtpbvpay: RTP BV Payloader
rtp:  rtpceltdepay: RTP CELT depayloader
rtp:  rtpceltpay: RTP CELT payloader
rtp:  rtpdvdepay: RTP DV Depayloader
rtp:  rtpdvpay: RTP DV Payloader
rtp:  rtpgstdepay: GStreamer depayloader
rtp:  rtpgstpay: RTP GStreamer payloader
rtp:  rtpilbcpay: RTP iLBC Payloader
rtp:  rtpilbcdepay: RTP iLBC depayloader
rtp:  rtpg722depay: RTP audio depayloader
rtp:  rtpg722pay: RTP audio payloader
rtp:  rtpg723depay: RTP G.723 depayloader
rtp:  rtpg723pay: RTP G.723 payloader
rtp:  rtpg726depay: RTP G.726 depayloader
rtp:  rtpg726pay: RTP G.726 payloader
rtp:  rtpg729depay: RTP G.729 depayloader
rtp:  rtpg729pay: RTP G.729 payloader
rtp:  rtpgsmdepay: RTP GSM depayloader
rtp:  rtpgsmpay: RTP GSM payloader
rtp:  rtpamrdepay: RTP AMR depayloader
rtp:  rtpamrpay: RTP AMR payloader
rtp:  rtppcmadepay: RTP PCMA depayloader
rtp:  rtppcmudepay: RTP PCMU depayloader
rtp:  rtppcmupay: RTP PCMU payloader
rtp:  rtppcmapay: RTP PCMA payloader
rtp:  rtpmpadepay: RTP MPEG audio depayloader
rtp:  rtpmpapay: RTP MPEG audio payloader
rtp:  rtpmparobustdepay: RTP MPEG audio depayloader
rtp:  rtpmpvdepay: RTP MPEG video depayloader
rtp:  rtpmpvpay: RTP MPEG2 ES video payloader
rtp:  rtpopusdepay: RTP Opus packet depayloader
rtp:  rtpopuspay: RTP Opus payloader
rtp:  rtph261pay: RTP H261 packet payloader
rtp:  rtph261depay: RTP H261 depayloader
rtp:  rtph263ppay: RTP H263 payloader
rtp:  rtph263pdepay: RTP H263 depayloader
rtp:  rtph263depay: RTP H263 depayloader
rtp:  rtph263pay: RTP H263 packet payloader
rtp:  rtph264depay: RTP H264 depayloader
rtp:  rtph264pay: RTP H264 payloader
rtp:  rtph265depay: RTP H265 depayloader
rtp:  rtph265pay: RTP H265 payloader
rtp:  rtpj2kdepay: RTP JPEG 2000 depayloader
rtp:  rtpj2kpay: RTP JPEG 2000 payloader
rtp:  rtpjpegdepay: RTP JPEG depayloader
rtp:  rtpjpegpay: RTP JPEG payloader
rtp:  rtpklvdepay: RTP KLV Depayloader
rtp:  rtpklvpay: RTP KLV Payloader
rtp:  rtpL16pay: RTP audio payloader
rtp:  rtpL16depay: RTP audio depayloader
rtp:  rtpL24pay: RTP audio payloader
rtp:  rtpL24depay: RTP audio depayloader
rtp:  asteriskh263: RTP Asterisk H263 depayloader
rtp:  rtpmp1sdepay: RTP MPEG1 System Stream depayloader
rtp:  rtpmp2tdepay: RTP MPEG Transport Stream depayloader
rtp:  rtpmp2tpay: RTP MPEG2 Transport Stream payloader
rtp:  rtpmp4vpay: RTP MPEG4 Video payloader
rtp:  rtpmp4vdepay: RTP MPEG4 video depayloader
rtp:  rtpmp4apay: RTP MPEG4 audio payloader
rtp:  rtpmp4adepay: RTP MPEG4 audio depayloader
rtp:  rtpmp4gdepay: RTP MPEG4 ES depayloader
rtp:  rtpmp4gpay: RTP MPEG4 ES payloader
rtp:  rtpqcelpdepay: RTP QCELP depayloader
rtp:  rtpqdm2depay: RTP QDM2 depayloader
rtp:  rtpsbcdepay: RTP SBC audio depayloader
rtp:  rtpsbcpay: RTP packet payloader
rtp:  rtpsirenpay: RTP Payloader for Siren Audio
rtp:  rtpsirendepay: RTP Siren packet depayloader
rtp:  rtpspeexpay: RTP Speex payloader
rtp:  rtpspeexdepay: RTP Speex depayloader
rtp:  rtpsv3vdepay: RTP SVQ3 depayloader
rtp:  rtptheoradepay: RTP Theora depayloader
rtp:  rtptheorapay: RTP Theora payloader
rtp:  rtpvorbisdepay: RTP Vorbis depayloader
rtp:  rtpvorbispay: RTP Vorbis payloader
rtp:  rtpvp8depay: RTP VP8 depayloader
rtp:  rtpvp8pay: RTP VP8 payloader
rtp:  rtpvp9depay: RTP VP9 depayloader
rtp:  rtpvp9pay: RTP VP9 payloader
rtp:  rtpvrawdepay: RTP Raw Video depayloader
rtp:  rtpvrawpay: RTP Raw Video payloader
rtp:  rtpstreampay: RTP Stream Payloading
rtp:  rtpstreamdepay: RTP Stream Depayloading
rtpmanager:  rtpbin: RTP Bin
rtpmanager:  rtpjitterbuffer: RTP packet jitter-buffer
rtpmanager:  rtpptdemux: RTP Demux
rtpmanager:  rtpsession: RTP Session
rtpmanager:  rtprtxqueue: RTP Retransmission Queue
rtpmanager:  rtprtxreceive: RTP Retransmission receiver
rtpmanager:  rtprtxsend: RTP Retransmission Sender
rtpmanager:  rtpssrcdemux: RTP SSRC Demux
rtpmanager:  rtpmux: RTP muxer
rtpmanager:  rtpdtmfmux: RTP muxer
autodetect:  autovideosink: Auto video sink
autodetect:  autovideosrc: Auto video source
autodetect:  autoaudiosink: Auto audio sink
autodetect:  autoaudiosrc: Auto audio source
effectv:  edgetv: EdgeTV effect
effectv:  agingtv: AgingTV effect
effectv:  dicetv: DiceTV effect
effectv:  warptv: WarpTV effect
effectv:  shagadelictv: ShagadelicTV
effectv:  vertigotv: VertigoTV effect
effectv:  revtv: RevTV effect
effectv:  quarktv: QuarkTV effect
effectv:  optv: OpTV effect
effectv:  radioactv: RadioacTV effect
effectv:  streaktv: StreakTV effect
effectv:  rippletv: RippleTV effect
debug:  breakmydata: Break my data
debug:  capssetter: CapsSetter
debug:  rndbuffersize: Random buffer size
debug:  navseek: Seek based on left-right arrows
debug:  pushfilesrc: Push File Source
debug:  progressreport: Progress report
debug:  taginject: TagInject
debug:  testsink: Test plugin
debug:  cpureport: CPU report
shout2send:  shout2send: Icecast network sink
flxdec:  flxdec: FLX video decoder
jpegformat:  jpegparse: JPEG stream parser
jpegformat:  jifmux: JPEG stream muxer
vpx:  vp8dec: On2 VP8 Decoder
vpx:  vp8enc: On2 VP8 Encoder
vpx:  vp9dec: On2 VP9 Decoder
vpx:  vp9enc: On2 VP9 Encoder
pulseaudio:  pulsesink: PulseAudio Audio Sink
pulseaudio:  pulsesrc: PulseAudio Audio Source
pulseaudio:  pulsedeviceprovider (GstDeviceProviderFactory)
udp:  udpsink: UDP packet sender
udp:  multiudpsink: UDP packet sender
udp:  dynudpsink: UDP packet sender
udp:  udpsrc: UDP packet receiver
navigationtest:  navigationtest: Video navigation test
cacasink:  cacasink: A colored ASCII art video sink
ximagesrc:  ximagesrc: Ximage video source
smpte:  smpte: SMPTE transitions
smpte:  smptealpha: SMPTE transitions
auparse:  auparse: AU audio demuxer
video4linux2:  v4l2src: Video (video4linux2) Source
video4linux2:  v4l2sink: Video (video4linux2) Sink
video4linux2:  v4l2radio: Radio (video4linux2) Tuner
video4linux2:  v4l2deviceprovider (GstDeviceProviderFactory)
audiofx:  audiopanorama: Stereo positioning
audiofx:  audioinvert: Audio inversion
audiofx:  audiokaraoke: AudioKaraoke
audiofx:  audioamplify: Audio amplifier
audiofx:  audiodynamic: Dynamic range controller
audiofx:  audiocheblimit: Low pass & high pass filter
audiofx:  audiochebband: Band pass & band reject filter
audiofx:  audioiirfilter: Audio IIR filter
audiofx:  audiowsinclimit: Low pass & high pass filter
audiofx:  audiowsincband: Band pass & band reject filter
audiofx:  audiofirfilter: Audio FIR filter
audiofx:  audioecho: Audio echo
audiofx:  scaletempo: Scaletempo
alpha:  alpha: Alpha filter
mulaw:  mulawenc: Mu Law audio encoder
mulaw:  mulawdec: Mu Law audio decoder
gdkpixbuf:  gdkpixbufdec: GdkPixbuf image decoder
gdkpixbuf:  gdkpixbufoverlay: GdkPixbuf Overlay
gdkpixbuf:  gdkpixbufsink: GdkPixbuf sink
videofilter:  gamma: Video gamma correction
videofilter:  videobalance: Video balance
videofilter:  videoflip: Video flipper
videofilter:  videomedian: Median effect
wavenc:  wavenc: WAV audio muxer
wavpack:  wavpackdec: Wavpack audio decoder
wavpack:  wavpackenc: Wavpack audio encoder
multifile:  multifilesrc: Multi-File Source
multifile:  multifilesink: Multi-File Sink
multifile:  splitfilesrc: Split-File Source
multifile:  splitmuxsink: Split Muxing Bin
multifile:  splitmuxsrc: Split File Demuxing Bin
flv:  flvdemux: FLV Demuxer
flv:  flvmux: FLV muxer
videocrop:  videocrop: Crop
videocrop:  aspectratiocrop: aspectratiocrop
matroska:  matroskademux: Matroska demuxer
matroska:  matroskaparse: Matroska parser
matroska:  matroskamux: Matroska muxer
matroska:  webmmux: WebM muxer
1394:  dv1394src: Firewire (1394) DV video source
1394:  hdv1394src: Firewire (1394) HDV video source
cutter:  cutter: Audio cutter
oss4:  oss4sink: OSS v4 Audio Sink
oss4:  oss4src: OSS v4 Audio Source
alphacolor:  alphacolor: Alpha color filter
level:  level: Level
ossaudio:  osssrc: Audio Source (OSS)
ossaudio:  osssink: Audio Sink (OSS)
camerabin:  viewfinderbin: Viewfinder Bin
camerabin:  wrappercamerabinsrc: Wrapper camera src element for camerabin2
camerabin:  camerabin: Camera Bin
replaygain:  rganalysis: ReplayGain analysis
replaygain:  rglimiter: ReplayGain limiter
replaygain:  rgvolume: ReplayGain volume
aasink:  aasink: ASCII art video sink
apetag:  apedemux: APE tag demuxer
shapewipe:  shapewipe: Shape Wipe transition filter
alaw:  alawenc: A Law audio encoder
alaw:  alawdec: A Law audio decoder
interleave:  interleave: Audio interleaver
interleave:  deinterleave: Audio deinterleaver
audioparsers:  aacparse: AAC audio stream parser
audioparsers:  amrparse: AMR audio stream parser
audioparsers:  ac3parse: AC3 audio stream parser
audioparsers:  dcaparse: DTS Coherent Acoustics audio stream parser
audioparsers:  flacparse: FLAC audio parser
audioparsers:  mpegaudioparse: MPEG1 Audio Parser
audioparsers:  sbcparse: SBC audio parser
audioparsers:  wavpackparse: Wavpack audio stream parser
deinterlace:  deinterlace: Deinterlacer
multipart:  multipartdemux: Multipart demuxer
multipart:  multipartmux: Multipart muxer
png:  pngdec: PNG image decoder
png:  pngenc: PNG image encoder
jpeg:  jpegenc: JPEG image encoder
jpeg:  jpegdec: JPEG image decoder
y4menc:  y4menc: YUV4MPEG video encoder
dv:  dvdemux: DV system stream demuxer
dv:  dvdec: DV video decoder
taglib:  id3v2mux: TagLib-based ID3v2 Muxer
taglib:  apev2mux: TagLib-based APEv2 Muxer
icydemux:  icydemux: ICY tag demuxer
cairo:  cairooverlay: Cairo overlay
equalizer:  equalizer-nbands: N Band Equalizer
equalizer:  equalizer-3bands: 3 Band Equalizer
equalizer:  equalizer-10bands: 10 Band Equalizer
id3demux:  id3demux: ID3 tag demuxer
jack:  jackaudiosrc: Audio Source (Jack)
jack:  jackaudiosink: Audio Sink (Jack)
isomp4:  qtdemux: QuickTime demuxer
isomp4:  rtpxqtdepay: RTP packet depayloader
isomp4:  qtmux: QuickTime Muxer
isomp4:  mp4mux: MP4 Muxer
isomp4:  ismlmux: ISML Muxer
isomp4:  3gppmux: 3GPP Muxer
isomp4:  mj2mux: MJ2 Muxer
isomp4:  qtmoovrecover: QT Moov Recover
speex:  speexenc: Speex audio encoder
speex:  speexdec: Speex audio decoder
gio:  giostreamsrc: GIO stream source
gio:  giostreamsink: GIO stream sink
gio:  giosrc: GIO source
gio:  giosink: GIO sink
audioconvert:  audioconvert: Audio converter
vorbis:  vorbistag: VorbisTag
vorbis:  vorbisparse: VorbisParse
vorbis:  vorbisdec: Vorbis audio decoder
vorbis:  vorbisenc: Vorbis audio encoder
volume:  volume: Volume
subparse:  ssaparse: SSA Subtitle Parser
subparse:  subparse: Subtitle parser
subparse: subparse_typefind: srt, sub, mpsub, mdvd, smi, txt, dks
typefindfunctions: audio/audible: aa, aax
typefindfunctions: audio/x-xi: xi
typefindfunctions: video/x-pva: pva
typefindfunctions: application/x-ssa: ssa, ass
typefindfunctions: application/octet-stream: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/x-degas: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/x-icon: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-yuv4mpeg: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/vnd.wap.wbmp: no extensions
typefindfunctions: image/vnd.adobe.photoshop: psd
typefindfunctions: application/msword: doc
typefindfunctions: application/pdf: pdf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-kss: kss
typefindfunctions: video/x-ivf: ivf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sap: sap
typefindfunctions: audio/x-vgm: vgm
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gbs: gbs
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ay: ay
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gym: gym
typefindfunctions: audio/x-nsf: nsf
typefindfunctions: video/vivo: viv
typefindfunctions: application/x-mmsh: no extensions
typefindfunctions: multipart/x-mixed-replace: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/x-dirac: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ms-dos-executable: dll, exe, ocx, sys, scr, msstyles, cpl
typefindfunctions: application/x-ar: a
typefindfunctions: application/x-tar: tar
typefindfunctions: application/x-rar: rar
typefindfunctions: image/svg+xml: svg
typefindfunctions: application/postscript: ps
typefindfunctions: audio/x-caf: caf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack-correction: wvc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wavpack: wv, wvp
typefindfunctions: audio/x-spc: spc
typefindfunctions: audio/aac: aac, adts, adif, loas
typefindfunctions: application/x-executable: no extensions
typefindfunctions: text/x-cmml: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogg-skeleton: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-celt: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-speex: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-text: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-audio: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-ogm-video: no extensions
typefindfunctions: video/x-theora: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-vorbis: no extensions
typefindfunctions: audio/x-flac: flac
typefindfunctions: subtitle/x-kate: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/x-compress: Z
typefindfunctions: application/zip: zip
typefindfunctions: application/x-gzip: gz
typefindfunctions: application/x-bzip: bz2
typefindfunctions: image/x-sun-raster: ras
typefindfunctions: image/x-xpixmap: xpm
typefindfunctions: image/x-jng: jng
typefindfunctions: video/x-mng: mng
typefindfunctions: image/x-xcf: xcf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sid: sid
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sbc: sbc
typefindfunctions: audio/iLBC-sh: ilbc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-amr-wb-sh: amr
typefindfunctions: audio/x-amr-nb-sh: amr
typefindfunctions: video/x-dv: dv, dif
typefindfunctions: video/x-mve: mve
typefindfunctions: application/mxf: mxf
typefindfunctions: video/x-matroska: mkv, mka, mk3d, webm
typefindfunctions: image/x-portable-pixmap: pnm, ppm, pgm, pbm
typefindfunctions: image/x-exr: exr
typefindfunctions: image/webp: webp
typefindfunctions: image/tiff: tif, tiff
typefindfunctions: image/bmp: bmp
typefindfunctions: image/png: png
typefindfunctions: image/gif: gif
typefindfunctions: image/jpeg: jpg, jpe, jpeg
typefindfunctions: application/x-ape: ape
typefindfunctions: audio/x-shorten: shn
typefindfunctions: audio/x-rf64: rf64
typefindfunctions: audio/x-w64: w64
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ircam: sf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-sds: sds
typefindfunctions: audio/x-voc: voc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-nist: nist
typefindfunctions: audio/x-paris: paf
typefindfunctions: audio/x-svx: iff, svx
typefindfunctions: audio/x-aiff: aiff, aif, aifc
typefindfunctions: audio/x-wav: wav
typefindfunctions: application/xml: xml
typefindfunctions: application/ttml+xml: ttml+xml
typefindfunctions: application/smil: smil
typefindfunctions: application/sdp: sdp
typefindfunctions: application/x-hls: m3u8
typefindfunctions: text/uri-list: ram
typefindfunctions: text/utf-32: txt
typefindfunctions: text/utf-16: txt
typefindfunctions: text/plain: txt
typefindfunctions: video/x-flv: flv
typefindfunctions: application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml: no extensions
typefindfunctions: application/dash+xml: mpd, MPD
typefindfunctions: application/x-shockwave-flash: swf, swfl
typefindfunctions: application/x-pn-realaudio: ra, ram, rm, rmvb
typefindfunctions: application/vnd.rn-realmedia: ra, ram, rm, rmvb
typefindfunctions: text/html: htm, html
typefindfunctions: video/mj2: mj2
typefindfunctions: image/jp2: jp2
typefindfunctions: image/x-quicktime: qif, qtif, qti
typefindfunctions: video/quicktime: mov, mp4
typefindfunctions: application/x-3gp: 3gp
typefindfunctions: audio/x-m4a: m4a
typefindfunctions: video/x-nuv: nuv
typefindfunctions: video/x-h265: h265, x265, 265
typefindfunctions: video/x-h264: h264, x264, 264
typefindfunctions: video/x-h263: h263, 263
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg4: m4v
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg-elementary: mpv, mpeg, mpg
typefindfunctions: application/ogg: ogg, oga, ogv, ogm, ogx, spx, anx, axa, axv
typefindfunctions: video/mpegts: ts, mts
typefindfunctions: video/mpeg-sys: mpe, mpeg, mpg
typefindfunctions: audio/x-gsm: gsm
typefindfunctions: audio/x-dts: dts
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ac3: ac3, eac3
typefindfunctions: audio/mpeg: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga
typefindfunctions: audio/x-mod: 669, amf, ams, dbm, digi, dmf, dsm, gdm, far, imf, it, j2b, mdl, med, mod, mt2, mtm, okt, psm, ptm, sam, s3m, stm, stx, ult, umx, xm
typefindfunctions: audio/x-ttafile: tta
typefindfunctions: application/x-apetag: mp3, ape, mpc, wv
typefindfunctions: application/x-id3v1: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga, ogg, flac, tta
typefindfunctions: application/x-id3v2: mp3, mp2, mp1, mpga, ogg, flac, tta
typefindfunctions: video/x-fli: flc, fli
typefindfunctions: audio/mobile-xmf: mxmf
typefindfunctions: audio/riff-midi: mid, midi
typefindfunctions: audio/midi: mid, midi
typefindfunctions: audio/x-imelody: imy, ime, imelody
typefindfunctions: video/x-vcd: dat
typefindfunctions: video/x-cdxa: dat
typefindfunctions: audio/qcelp: qcp
typefindfunctions: video/x-msvideo: avi
typefindfunctions: audio/x-au: au, snd
typefindfunctions: audio/x-musepack: mpc, mpp, mp+
typefindfunctions: video/x-ms-asf: asf, wm, wma, wmv
theora:  theoraparse: Theora video parser
theora:  theoraenc: Theora video encoder
theora:  theoradec: Theora video decoder
cdparanoia:  cdparanoiasrc: CD Audio (cdda) Source, Paranoia IV
videotestsrc:  videotestsrc: Video test source
audiotestsrc:  audiotestsrc: Audio test source
pango:  textrender: Text renderer
pango:  clockoverlay: Clock overlay
pango:  timeoverlay: Time overlay
pango:  textoverlay: Text overlay
playback:  uridecodebin: URI Decoder
playback:  decodebin: Decoder Bin
playback:  streamsynchronizer: Stream Synchronizer
playback:  subtitleoverlay: Subtitle Overlay
playback:  playsink: Player Sink
playback:  playbin: Player Bin 2
audioresample:  audioresample: Audio resampler
audiorate:  audiorate: Audio rate adjuster
app:  appsink: AppSink
app:  appsrc: AppSrc
videoscale:  videoscale: Video scaler
xvimagesink:  xvimagesink: Video sink
ximagesink:  ximagesink: Video sink
adder:  adder: Adder
ogg:  oggaviparse: Ogg AVI parser
ogg:  oggparse: Ogg parser
ogg:  ogmtextparse: OGM text stream parser
ogg:  ogmvideoparse: OGM video stream parser
ogg:  ogmaudioparse: OGM audio stream parser
ogg:  oggmux: Ogg muxer
ogg:  oggdemux: Ogg demuxer
opus:  opusdec: Opus audio decoder
opus:  opusenc: Opus audio encoder
tcp:  multisocketsink: Multi socket sink
tcp:  multifdsink: Multi filedescriptor sink
tcp:  tcpserversrc: TCP server source
tcp:  tcpserversink: TCP server sink
tcp:  tcpclientsrc: TCP client source
tcp:  tcpclientsink: TCP client sink
tcp:  socketsrc: socket source
alsa:  alsamidisrc: AlsaMidi Source
alsa:  alsasink: Audio sink (ALSA)
alsa:  alsasrc: Audio source (ALSA)
videoconvert:  videoconvert: Colorspace converter
videorate:  videorate: Video rate adjuster
encoding:  encodebin: Encoder Bin
coretracers:  stats (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  rusage (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  log (GstTracerFactory)
coretracers:  latency (GstTracerFactory)
clutter-gst3:  clutterautovideosink: Clutter Auto Video Sink
coreelements:  streamiddemux: Streamid Demux
coreelements:  valve: Valve element
coreelements:  multiqueue: MultiQueue
coreelements:  typefind: TypeFind
coreelements:  tee: Tee pipe fitting
coreelements:  filesink: File Sink
coreelements:  queue2: Queue 2
coreelements:  queue: Queue
coreelements:  output-selector: Output selector
coreelements:  input-selector: Input selector
coreelements:  identity: Identity
coreelements:  funnel: Funnel pipe fitting
coreelements:  filesrc: File Source
coreelements:  fdsink: Filedescriptor Sink
coreelements:  fdsrc: Filedescriptor Source
coreelements:  fakesink: Fake Sink
coreelements:  fakesrc: Fake Source
coreelements:  downloadbuffer: DownloadBuffer
coreelements:  concat: Concat
coreelements:  capsfilter: CapsFilter
staticelements:  bin: Generic bin
staticelements:  pipeline: Pipeline object
```

With regards to the QTmultimedia version, I have the 5.0 one.

Answer (score 0):

Please try "gst-pipeline" source option instead.

One example:

```
MediaPlayer {
        id: player
        source: "gst-pipeline: filesrc location=your_path" + sourceFile + " ! decodebin name=dec ! videoconvert ! waylandsink"
```

You can also replace "waylandsink" by "qtvideosink" depending on your configuration.

Comment: I used two gstreamer pipeline 

`"gst-pipeline: filesrc location=/home/root/media/video_test.mp4 ! decodebin name=dec ! videoconvert ! qtvideosink"` and

`"gst-pipeline: filesrc location=/home/root/media/video_test.mp4 ! decodebin name=dec ! videoconvert ! waylandvideosink"`

but I have the following error

`Error: "No URI handler implemented for \"gst-pipeline\"."`